# Showing custom alert while leaving a page

Tags: javascript

I want to show a alert while body OnUnload or onbeforeunload  function but alerts are not working on both. Based on the alert output I need to submit a form .
I used **return 'msg';** but here I dont konw the value clicked by the user.
Any solution for this

```
<body  onload="init()" onUnLoad="clean_exit()">

function clean_exit( ){    

 if(changes){         
  if (!confirm("Save changes")){ 
   return false;  
  }else{   

   document[page].submit();    
  }
```

Confirm is not working here

Is there any method to do this, need help

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Code added in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a listeners in the js-file:

```
document.body.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.body.addEventListener('before_unload', clean_exit);
});

function clean_exit() {    
    if (changes) {         
        !confirm("Save changes") ? return false : document[page].submit();    
    }
}
```